# WCF Service Reference - proxy not being generated when reusing types

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have two C# (.NET v4.0) companion projects, a ASP.NET website and a "self-hosted" WCF Console application. The website code calls the WCF service for various things; both were written a couple of years ago, and have been working fine.

Both the console app and web site share a common class library between them (called `MyLibrary` in this example); this is added as a reference to both projects.

The console app is pretty simple - for example, I have `IService.cs`:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{               
    [OperationContract]
    List<MyLibrary.MyClass> DoSomething(int ID);
}
```

and then `Service.cs`:

```
public class Service : IService
{
    public List<MyLibrary.MyClass> DoSomething(int ID)
    {
        // etc
        return result;
    }
}
```

... and all of this works. However, today I've needed to add something trivial to both sides - one of the methods needs to have another parameter added. I've updated the WCF app, built it, ran it, and then gone to the website and tried to "Update Service Reference".

At this point, the site broke: generating the service reference is no longer creating a proxy. However, if I deselect the option to "Reuse all references", the proxy is created: this breaks my code massively though, I need to share the references to `MyLibrary` all through the code.

After doing some digging, I've attempted to create the reference using `svcutil`:

`svcutil /t:code http://localhost/MyService /r MyLibrary.dll`

which throws the error:

```
Attempting to download metadata from 'http://localhost/MyService' using WS-Metadata Exchange or DISCO. Error: Cannot import wsdl:portType Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter    
Error: Referenced type 'MyLibrary.MyClass, MyLibrary, Version=2.0.53
33.26816, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' with data contract name 'MyLibrary.MyClass' in namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyService' cannot be used since it does not match imported DataContract. Need to exclude this type from referenced types.    
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:portType[@name='IService']
```

I cannot figure out what's gone wrong; I've seen other posts about this error, but they all mention making sure the referenced class is the same - the WCF app is using the same code in `MyLibrary` as I'm calling with `svcutil` above; both are being compiled at the same time. Also, I'm not doing anything differently that I haven't done dozens of times before.

Can anyone suggest where to start troubleshooting this issue? Apologies in advance if I've mangled any of the syntax in my code examples during obfuscation :)

Comment: what is the targeted framework for MyLibrary library? From the error it looks like, it was compiled with Framework 2.0 which may be creating an issue. are you able to compile WCF without any error?

Comment: Everything's set to target .Net v4.0 - I'm using some stuff that simply didn't exist in earlier version. The WCF app compiles fine.

Comment: Check out this article. [WCF Client Code Generation - Issue with "Reuse types from referenced assemblies" option in Add Service Reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2010/02/04/wcf-client-issue-with-reuse-types-from-referenced-assemblies.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0). Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I've been through that article already. I'm not using a "DataContract" (not sure if I should be? Everything's been OK up until now...), and the only option that would suit me (number 2) is about changing the DataContract parameters.

Comment: You may need to use DataContract. Btw, what error are you getting while updating reference?

Comment: OK - why the need for a DataContract all of the sudden? I don't get an error whilst updating the reference, just my code (that relies on a proxy) stops working.

Comment: DataContract is the agreement between service and the client to exchange the data. Btw, is it possible for u to host it on server and provide me the details for MyLibrary class and service Url, so i can dig into it?

Comment: Thanks - I appear to have fixed it (see below), more by accident than anything: I need to skill up on all things WCF, I think I've been fortunate that this has "just worked" up until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've inadvertently stumbled over the answer: if I uncheck the "Always generate message contracts" option, and then "Update Service Reference", everything goes back to normal.

[image]

I'm certain I should really be using a DataContract (as mentioned in the comments on my OP), but I'll take the quick win and hide my ignorance for another day!